# DataBinding causing a Kotlin compiler error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I have following branch in Bitbucket : https://bitbucket.org/ali-rezaei/tmdb/src/dataBinding/

I get following `Kotlin compiler` error when I build the project :

```
e: [kapt] An exception occurred: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
```

Error is related to :

```
app:visibleGone="@{isLoaded}"
```

in the following layout :

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="isLoaded"
            type="boolean" />
    </data>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:visibleGone="@{isLoaded}" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        <include
            layout="@layout/network_state_item"
            app:visibleGone="@{!isLoaded}" />

    </FrameLayout>

</layout>
```

I appreciate if you can help me out.

Comment: `app:visibleGone` . Post the `@BindingAdapter` annotated method

Comment: I'm curious if it's because of your variable type, what'd happen if you change `boolean` to `Boolean`? Or even `java.lang.Boolean`?

Comment: @Blackbelt https://bitbucket.org/ali-rezaei/tmdb/src/dataBinding/app/src/main/java/com/sample/android/tmdb/ui/MainFragment.kt, thanks

Comment: @Aaron, I got the same error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The changes I would do are: Here

```
<variable
        name="isLoaded"
        type="boolean" />
```

Instead of passing `boolean` I would pass an instance of your VM

```
   <variable
        name="vm"
        type="com.sample.android.tmdb.ui.MovieViewModel" />
```

in your fragment, you do

```
    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
    mBinding?.setVariable(BR.vm, mViewModel)
    mBinding?.setLifecycleOwner(this)
```

this way, your VM is connected to the lifecycle of your fragment.

Declare a method

```
  @BindingAdapter("visibleGone")
  fun View.visibleGone(visible: Boolean) {
      setVisibility(if (visible) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE)
  }
```

declare a `LiveData<Boolean>` variable in you `MovieViewModel` and connect it in your layout. Eg.

```
 val loading: LiveData<Boolean>
```

then in your layout you could have

```
       <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:visibleGone="@{!safeUnbox(vm.loading)}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, BR.`vm` is not recognized. I tried both `import com.android.databinding.library.baseAdapters.BR` and `import com.sample.android.tmdb.BR`

Comment: did you build ? Push on a different branch and past here the link

Comment: Yes, it was related to build. Now I just get `network_state_item` layout and not RecyclerView

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/ali-rezaei/tmdb/src/new-dataBinding/app/src/main/res/layout/network_state_item.xml

Comment: try adding `android:layout_width` `android:layout_height` and `android:id` to the include

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183553/discussion-between-ali-and-blackbelt).

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different problem that generated this error.
In my ViewModel, I had the following method:

```
`fun onSkip() {
    _score.value = (_score.value)?.minus(1)
    nextWord()
}`
```

Now, when i was setting the onClick attributes in my xml, I set them like this:

```
android:onClick="@{() -> gameViewModel.onSkip}" 

                 instead of
```

`android:onClick="@{() -> gameViewModel.onSkip()}"`

Notice how I forgot to use the parenthesis in the first method.